# Replacing using named capture groups in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's find and replace tool:

[image: Screenshot of find/replace tool]

My regex: `<h2>(?<title>.*?)</h2>`

I'd like to use my named capture group in the replace string. I know I can use `$1` to refer to the first capture group, but I'd like to use its name.

I've tried to no avail:

- `$title`
- `$<title>`
- `$'title'`
- `$"title"`
- `$(title)`
- `$[title]`
- `$['title']`
- `$["title"]`
- `$("title")`
- `$('title')`
- `$[<title>]`
- `$['<title>']`
- `$["<title>"]`
- `$('<title>')`
- `$("<title>")`
- `$<"title">`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I stumbled on the solution to this while trying to use a named capture group in IntelliJ. <strike>I haven't been able to find documentation on it.</strike>

The [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference) now shows how this is done (thanks @Pang):

- Numbered capture groups use `$n` e.g. *find:* `<h2>(.*?)</h2>` *replace:* `$1`.
- Named capture groups use `${<name>}` e.g. *find:* `<h2>(?<title>.*?)</h2>` *replace:* `${title}`

Comment: The regex formats should be same as the java documentation for regex pattern matching https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html as per the. Intellij documentation.

Comment: IntelliJ help doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference

Comment: This also works in Jetbrain's Rider.